# Vaadin 23 VirtualList with 50 or more items loses ClickListener and is not refreshed

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23, virtuallistview

**Context**: In a Vaadin 23.1.3 application there's a `VirtualList` with items with a `ClickListener` that refreshes the content of the item.

**What works**: When there are 3 items in the `VirtualList`, the `ClickListener` works fine and after calling `callingRefreshItem` the item in the `VirtualList` is re-rendered.

This is how the `VirtualList` looks like after I clicked the item with id="id2" 6 times (the counter counts up (equals 6) and LocalDateTime is updated, as expected):

[image: VirtualList after some clicks]

**What does not work**: When there are 7000 items in the `VirtualList`, (a) the `ClickListener` stops working after calling `refreshItem` and (b) the item that should get refreshed (by `refreshItem`) is not refreshed.

This is how the list looks like with e.g. 7000 items after clicking some items (counter is not refreshed and LocalDateTime is not refreshed):

[image: VirtualList not refreshing]

**Code**:

```
@Route("sandbox")
public class SandboxView extends VerticalLayout {

private static class Item {
    String id;
    int clicked=0;
    public Item(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.id.equals(((Item)obj).id);
    }
}

public SandboxView() {
    int numberOfItems = 7000;
    VirtualList<Item> vlist = new VirtualList<>();
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++) {
        items.add(new Item("id"+i));
    }
    ListDataProvider<Item> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Item>(items);
    vlist.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
    vlist.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<Div, Item>(item -> {
            Div div = new Div();
            div.addClickListener(e -> {item.clicked++;System.out.println(item.id + " clicked "+item.clicked+"x");dataProvider.refreshItem(item, true);});
            div.add(item.id+" "+item.clicked+" " +LocalDateTime.now());
            return div;
        }
    ));
    this.add(vlist);
}
}
```

**Further observations**:

- It seems that this behavior starts with 50 items in the `VirtualList`.
- When I scroll away from a broken item and then scroll to the broken item back, the values at the item are refreshed, the `ClickListener` is present and I can use it a single time. Then I have to scroll away and back again.
- (Update) There is a JavaScript error in the browser: `The error has occurred in the JS code: '$0, $1, return $0.$connector.updateData($1)'` and this message:
  [image: JavaScript error message]

**Question**: How can I refresh an item in a large `VirtualList` without losing `ClickListener`s?

Comment: I think this could be a bug, and you should report it at https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues instead of StackOverflow question.

Comment: A bug report is here: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vaadin 23.1.6 this is fixed.

https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3487#issuecomment-1191292376